# What happens with already running process of a Linux user with low niceness priority

Tags: linux

Assuming:

A user has niceness value of 1 and uses 100% resources with long running processes.
A user with prio 0 (higher niceness prio) starts also a process.

What will happen? Will Linux end already running process of the user with low niceness prio or is niceness only relevant for newly starting processes and the user with high prio must wait until the low prio processes finish?